# Is there any good reason not to distribute StarCraft replays?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there any good reason not to distribute StarCraft replays -- like maybe security or something like that?  For that matter does blizzard or battle net have a social area that they maybe allow public download/viewing of replays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the biggest reasons that players do not want their playstyles to be found through people watching their replays. One of the biggest weapons you have against your opponent is the guessing game of what build order you use on what maps. If you tend to use a certain strategy on a certain map then your opponent can blindly go with a counter build and just win, simply based on your habits.

That said, players sometimes do release replay packs to their fans.

Blizzard themselves do not have a social area for the upload/download of replays but there are a few sites out there:

- [SC2 Replayed](http://www.sc2replayed.com/)
- [SC2 Replays](http://www.sc2-replays.net/en/replays/)

You'll need to download the replays and then open them up in Starcraft 2 to view yourself.

Comment: What about security -- are there any security issues?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by security issues in your question so I didn't address it. A reply file is a recording of a game, what is stored in there are the actions carried out, resources spent, etc. Anything you'd find in the game, not sure what security issues there may be.

Comment: @lucidquiet There should be no security issues. The replay file has your screen name embedded in it, along with any [All] chat you typed, but no login details or password or anything. I believe it does not even have your 3-digit code, so just from your replay someone could not even find you on Battle.net.

Answer (score 1):

There are no security issues. AFAIK a replay includes only your screen name, but not your unique number. This way no one knows your real account or can add or harass you ingame.

Some players do not like their replays to be public, here are a few reasons:

- They try out different strategies / variants which are not representative of their skill.
- They have a bad day or are on a loosing streak. No one likes to be a loser in public.
- They prepare for a tournament and want to hide their standard strategies.
- Some friend plays on their account during a visit.
- Some people feel pressured when they are "recorded".